# Redirect output strings which contains

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, terminal

I need to hide some strings which my script outputs, such as "Permission denied" in find command. I want to redirect them to /dev/null. How can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Just append `2>/dev/null` at the end of your `find` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like:

```
find . -type f ... 2>/dev/null
```

This command will find a file and will redirect any type of standard error like "permission denied" in your case to /dev/null.

Comment: Can you explain, please?